# Strange Ropsten Bug - transactionsRoot and recieptsRoot has same value

Tags: ropsten, block-header

I'm testing some stuff on Ropsten network and I've found strange block:

4138624
When I run (using web3 injected in Metamask):

web3.eth.getBlock(4138624,function(err,res){

console.log(res);

})

I'm getting strange result

transactionsRoot and recieptsRoot has same value

I've posted question also on reddit
https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/9jz5cm/strange_ropsten_bug/

I've noticed them, because for those

```
                    data = [];
                    data.push(res.parentHash);
                    data.push(res.sha3Uncles);
                    data.push(res.miner);
                    data.push(res.stateRoot);
                    data.push(res.transactionsRoot);
                    data.push(res.receiptsRoot);
                    data.push(res.logsBloom);
                    data.push(addPrefix(parseInt(res.difficulty).toString(16)));
                    data.push(addPrefix(res.number.toString(16)));
                    data.push(addPrefix(res.gasLimit.toString(16)));
                    data.push(addPrefix(res.gasUsed.toString(16)));
                    data.push(addPrefix(res.timestamp.toString(16)));
                    data.push(res.extraData);
                    data.push(res.mixHash);
                    data.push(res.nonce);
```

if(res.hash==="0x"+utils.keccak256(rlp.encode(data)){
   // OK
}else{
//Something wrong
}

returns incorrect hash (while for most works just fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a block without transaction https://ropsten.etherscan.io/block/4138624, so those fields are keccak256 of an empty array of bytes.

If you look at blocks for other networks like rinkeby or mainnet they will have the same value

- https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/block/3074567
- https://etherscan.io/block/6422766

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, 

but I also noticed, that when I'm compution blockchash 


for those blocks it returns incorrect hash